# Google AMP - show hidden field based on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, css, amp-html

ii know this can be done using javascript, but for a page with amp to be valid, no javascript code is allowed.

So what i want is to lets say have a country dropdown that when a country is selected, the hidden field containing the states of the selected country is displayed.

**Problems** :

1. no javascript is allowed in AMP pages.
2. without javascript i cannot sent a background ajax request to get the states of a selected country

Even if lets say i do this for just one country (i.e usa) and have a hidden field that contains the states of that country, how do i make it visible when USA is selected from the dropdown list, without javascript?? Pure css wise i do not think it is possible to do this?

AMP only supports the following events:

- submit
- submit-success
- submit-error

Any help on this is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you would use on="changed:" event on the drop-down to fire an AMP state change. The state can be a variable, that triggers the `[src]="dynamic url"` of another AMP state that gets the states data for you and pushes it into the hidden field, using, again, AMP state, and a hidden input field with `[value]="statename.valuename"`

using AMP is highly discouraged from a development, maintenance and feature stand-point. It's too much in it's infancy for any company to consider to adopt. Rather spend your time going through your code and re-use/simplify/speed up as much and to the best you can. There are a lot of people who are just downloading bootstrap templates from themeforest and don't consider that 90% of the features included, will never be used.

keep your footprint tiny, use pagespeed/pingdom tools to test. use lazy loading etc. tweak your server/cache as required. there is 0 need for AMP, nor will it be adopted as a standard.

it's just a crappy little idea that causes companies to adopt because "we will rank higher in google" and after month's of development, find the most basic fking features missing to the point where your company (who already thinks you are magic, and not just a programmer) wonders why you can't achieve marketing's goal of a dancing panda whenever someone submits a simple fking form